# Why does GraphServiceClient say I'm using okhttp3.Request eventhough I don't even import it?

Tags: java, maven, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to get the access token using Microsoft Graph SDK, this is the code:

```
import com.azure.identity.InteractiveBrowserCredential;
import com.azure.identity.InteractiveBrowserCredentialBuilder;
import com.microsoft.graph.authentication.TokenCredentialAuthProvider;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.User;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.Request;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.GraphServiceClient;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    static final String clientId = "XXX-XXX-XXX";
    static final String tenantId = "consumers";
    static final String redirectUrl = "http://localhost:8080";
    static final List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList("User.Read");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final InteractiveBrowserCredential credential = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialBuilder()              .clientId(clientId).tenantId(tenantId).redirectUrl(redirectUrl).build();

        final TokenCredentialAuthProvider authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(
                scopes, credential);

        GraphServiceClient<Request> graphClient =
                GraphServiceClient
                        .builder()
                        .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
                        .buildClient();

        User me = graphClient.me().buildRequest().get();

// Print the user's display name
        if (me != null) {
            System.out.println(me.displayName);
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see I don't import the `okhttp3` package but the IDE keeps saying that something is wrong with `GraphServiceClient<Request> graphClient = GraphServiceClient .builder() .authenticationProvider(authProvider) .buildClient();`

```
Required type: GraphServiceClient <com.microsoft.graph.models.Request>
Provided: GraphServiceClient <okhttp3.Request>
```

I know that Microsoft SDK uses `okhttp3` to make requests but I don't know where the conflict is.
Here's the `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ms</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
            <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
            <version>5.77.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.aad</groupId>
            <artifactId>adal4j</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>msal4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I did try to use other versions of the dependencies but the results are the same

Answer (score 0):

> **`Microsoft-graph`** package uses the Built-In **`Okhttp`** request method.

The `GraphServiceClient` class from the `Microsoft-graph` library uses the `okhttp3` library under the hood to make HTTP requests to the Microsoft Graph API. Even though you are not explicitly importing the `okhttp3` library in your code, it is still being used by the `GraphServiceClient` class.

You can try excluding the `okhttp3` dependency from the `Microsoft-graph` dependency and you can explicitly add `okhttp3` to your project with a version that is known to be compatible with the Microsoft Graph SDK.

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
    <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
    <version>5.77.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
    <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
    <version>4.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You can use the same code with the **`Okhttp`** method using Java:

**Code:**

```
import com.azure.identity.InteractiveBrowserCredential;
import com.azure.identity.InteractiveBrowserCredentialBuilder;
import com.microsoft.graph.authentication.TokenCredentialAuthProvider;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.User;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.GraphServiceClient;

import okhttp3.Request;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class App {
    static final String clientId = "xxxx";
    static final String tenantId = "7xxxx";
    static final String redirectUrl = "xxxx";
    static final List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList("User.Read");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final InteractiveBrowserCredential credential = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialBuilder().clientId(clientId).tenantId(tenantId).redirectUrl(redirectUrl).build();

        final TokenCredentialAuthProvider authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(
                scopes, credential);

                GraphServiceClient<Request> graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(authProvider).buildClient();

        User me = graphClient.me().buildRequest().get();

// Print the user's display name
        if (me != null) {
            System.out.println(me.displayName);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Display Name:Venkatesan
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have accidentally imported the wrong package.
Either type `GraphServiceClient<okhttp3.Request>` so that the InteliJ knows exactly which package it is or you replace

```
import com.microsoft.graph.models.Request;
```

with

```
import okhttp3.Request;
```